# Automating python operator overloading

Tags: python, operator-overloading

How can I automatically redefine all python operations about one of the properties of my Python class?

For example

```
class myInt():
    def __init__(self, val, name):
        self.val = val
        self.name = name
```

Now, I would like to define, addition, multiplication, and everything else about `self.val` **WITHOUT** having to explicitly redefine all the `__add__`, `__mul__`, ... .

Why? Because I would like to avoid writing 20+ functions since all I want is to operate on a single property of my class.

Comment: Define "everything else". Does this so-called "everything" include `__lt__`, `__eq__`, `__hash__`, `__neg__`, `__float__`, `__index__`, `__round__`, etc...?

Comment: Anything that applies to integers, so yes to all the things you listed.

Comment: One way: `def __getattr__(self, attr): return getattr(self.val, attr)` maybe with checking if `attr` is one of the desired functions. Other way: Create code as string (using a template and `format()`) and call `exec` on it.